# In Java, can I change a variable name in a for loop?

Tags: java

Is it possible to change a variable name every time a for loop loops itself?
`

```
for(int j=1;j<non-1;j++){
    int []newT=new int[non-j];
    for(int i=0;i<non-j;i++){
        newT[i]=pattern[i+1]-pattern[i];
        System.out.print(newT[i]+" ");
        System.out.println("");
        }}
```

`
Can I make the newT change every time the loop repeats, like after the for loop repeats, newT becomes new1, then new2, new3 and so on?

Comment: No. And it isn't clear why you would want such a thing.

Comment: Variable names don't exist at runtime. They are mere conveniences for you as you are reading and writing the code.

Comment: That is why arrays exist. Why not use a 2d array in this case?

Comment: You might possibly be looking for a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html).

Comment: If you ever think you want a long series of variables like `new1`, `new2`, `new3`, ... **stop**.  You need to use an array, `Map`, `List`, or some other structure that is designed to hold multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can not name it new1 but you can use 2d arrays and name it newT[ ][ ] and use it like newT[1][ ].
For example:

```
  for(int i = 0;i < n; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
         newT [i][j] = i*j;
         System.out.println(new [i][j]);
      }
  }
```

You can reach it now, as newT[1][ ], newT[2][ ] ...

Comment: Ummm... you can't use `new` as a variable name, because that word has another meaning.